# groupby and count on multiple columns of dataframe

Tags: pandas

I have a df

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
            [1, 1, 'A', 10], 
            [4, 1 ,'A', 6], 
            [7, 2 ,'A', 3],
            [2, 2 ,'A', 4],
            [6, 2 ,'B', 9],
            [5, 2 ,'B', 7],
            [5, 1 ,'B', 12],
            [5, 1 ,'B', 4],
            [5, 2 ,'C', 9],
            [5, 1 ,'C', 3],
            [5, 1 ,'C', 4],
            [5, 2 ,'C', 7]
            ],
         index=['A', 'A', 'A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A'],
         columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])
```

I can count the number of non zero values for column D grouped by column A using:

```
df['countTrans'] = df['D'].ne(0).groupby(df['A']).transform('sum')
```

where the output is:

```
df:
   A  B  C  D   countTrans
A  1  1  A  10         1.0
A  4  1  A   0         0.0
A  7  2  A   3         1.0
A  2  2  A   4         1.0
A  6  2  B   9         1.0
A  5  2  B   7         7.0
A  5  1  B  12         7.0
A  5  1  B   4         7.0
A  5  2  C   9         7.0
A  5  1  C   3         7.0
A  5  1  C   4         7.0
A  5  2  C   7         7.0
```

however I would like to also group by not only by column A but also column B.
I have tried variants of:

```
df['countTrans'] = df['D'].ne(0).groupby(df['A'], df['B']).transform('sum')
```

```
df['countTrans'] = df['D'].ne(0).groupby(df['A','B']).transform('sum')
```

without success

my desired output would look like:

```
df:
   A  B  C  D   countTrans
A  1  1  A  10         1.0
A  4  1  A   0         0.0
A  7  2  A   3         1.0
A  2  2  A   4         1.0
A  6  2  B   9         1.0
A  5  2  B   7         3.0
A  5  1  B  12         4.0
A  5  1  B   4         4.0
A  5  2  C   9         3.0
A  5  1  C   3         4.0
A  5  1  C   4         4.0
A  5  2  C   7         3.0
```

Answer (score 2):

Possible solution is pass `Series` to `list`:

```
df['countTrans'] = df['D'].ne(0).groupby([df['A'], df['B']]).transform('sum')
print (df)
   A  B  C   D  countTrans
A  1  1  A  10           1
A  4  1  A   6           1
A  7  2  A   3           1
A  2  2  A   4           1
A  6  2  B   9           1
A  5  2  B   7           3
A  5  1  B  12           4
A  5  1  B   4           4
A  5  2  C   9           3
A  5  1  C   3           4
A  5  1  C   4           4
A  5  2  C   7           3
```

Or create helper column by [`DataFrame.assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) (more `'clean'` in my opinion):

```
df['countTrans'] = df.assign(E = df['D'].ne(0)).groupby(['A','B'])['E'].transform('sum')
#similar solution with overwrite D
#df['countTrans'] = df.assign(D = df['D'].ne(0)).groupby(['A','B'])['D'].transform('sum')
```